# Implementing Custom Groups and Permissions for Organization Members in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I'm working on a Django project where I need to implement a feature that allows each organization to create groups and assign custom permissions to the members of those groups. I want to ensure that organization administrators can create specific groups only for their organization and assign limited permissions related to the app's features.

My "Organization" model is defined as follows:

```py
class Organization(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='owner_organizations')
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)
    pic = models.ImageField(upload_to="organizations/pics/", default='organizations/pics/default.png')
```

I also have an "OrganizationMember" model that links users to organizations:

```py
class OrganizationMember(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='organization_memberships')
    organization = models.ForeignKey(Organization, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='members')
    # Here, I want to figure out how to manage groups and custom permissions for members of each organization.
```

I noticed that Django provides default models for groups (django.contrib.auth.models.Group) and permissions (django.contrib.auth.models.Permission), but I'm not sure how to efficiently implement this feature.

How can I proceed to allow administrators of each organization to create groups and assign custom permissions to the members of those groups? I would also like to enable each member to be a part of multiple groups and have additional individual permissions.

I would greatly appreciate any suggestions, guidance, or examples on how to tackle this challenge in Django. Thank you very much!